# Spring Security 4 Concurrent Session Control not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying enable Concurrent Session Control in my Spring application using Spring security 4. Below are the code and configuration. But this is not working. It is allowing multiple session using same login.

Could you please let me know what is missing??

Security Configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.idearealty.product.shopchat" })
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true,securedEnabled = true,order=Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class SecSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;


    @Autowired
    private AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private HttpLogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

    public SecSecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.eraseCredentials(true).authenticationProvider(authProvider());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler d = new DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler();
        //d.setPermissionEvaluator(permissionEvaluator);
        web.debug(true)./*expressionHandler(d).*/ignoring().antMatchers("/favicon.ico","/resources/**");
    }

    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy getConcurrentSessionControlStrategy()
    {
        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy concurrenSessionControlStrategy= new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
        concurrenSessionControlStrategy.setMaximumSessions(1);
        concurrenSessionControlStrategy.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(false);

        SessionFixationProtectionStrategy sessionFixationProtectionStrategy = new SessionFixationProtectionStrategy();
        sessionFixationProtectionStrategy.setMigrateSessionAttributes(false);

        RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy = new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());

        List<SessionAuthenticationStrategy> strategies = new LinkedList<>();
        strategies.add(concurrenSessionControlStrategy);
        strategies.add(sessionFixationProtectionStrategy);
        strategies.add(registerSessionAuthenticationStrategy);

        CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy = new CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy(strategies);

        return compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        //.and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login*", "/logout*", "/signin/**", "/signup/**","/image/**","/useroperation/getLocality.json","/useroperation/getAllCities.json",
                "/user/registration*", "/regitrationConfirm*", "/user/regitrationConfirm*", "/expiredAccount*", "/registration*","/otpverification*","/user/otpverification*",
                "/badUser*", "/user/resendRegistrationToken*" ,"/forgetPassword*", "/user/resetPassword*","/user/regenerateOtp*","/products/getAllProductsByCategory**",
                "/user/changePassword*", "/emailError*", "/resources/**","/successRegister*","/anonymqestionanswer*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/invalidSession*").anonymous()
                .antMatchers("/admin","/admin/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .antMatchers("/admin","/admin/**").fullyAuthenticated()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html")
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                //.successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.html?logSucc=true")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                      .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(getConcurrentSessionControlStrategy())//.maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
                ;

        // @formatter:on
    }


    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
        return sessionRegistry;
    }

    // beans

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        //authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }
    /*
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }
     */
}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>localizationFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>localizationFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but what do you think limits connections in your config?

Comment: Thanks. I figured the problem. It was with hashcode & equals method of the bean.